# Laravel. Same colum orderBy two times

Tags: laravel

I have posts and want to order by date ascend, plus I want that posts where date is before today will go to after other posts. How I could do this?

Right now I got only this:

```
$posts = Post::orderBy('date', 'asc')->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `orderByRaw` for this:

```
$posts = Post::orderByRaw('DATE(`date`) < CURDATE()')
               ->orderBy('date', 'asc')
               ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

`I have posts and want to order by date ascend, plus I want that posts where date is before today will go to after other posts`

Perhaps this will suit your need:

1. First you need to get current time by `$current = Carbon::now()`
2. When post time is behind today, add up post time by current time and older posts will be put in the back of the result. Otherwise subtract post time by current time and newer posts will stand in the front. Here is the query: `Post::select('id', 'date', DB::raw('(CASE when date < '.$current.' then date+'.$current.' else date-'.$current.' END) AS new_post_time'))->orderBy('new_post_time', 'asc')->get();`

Now you can see post `id` is fetched as well as its original post `date`. Simply ignore `new_post_time` column if you do not need it.

Hope this helps. I have not run the query myself. There might be some errors.